# How can I index individual polygons in a SpatialPolygonDataFrame

Tags: polygon

I created 8 distinct polygons (sector_field) based on raster data (Gsectors) using:
sector_field <- rasterToPolygons(Gsectors,dissolve=T)

The polygons look correct, but I cannot figure out how to plot just one or a subset of the 8. I also do not know how they are numbered.

[Here's my raster data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67HMP.png)

[And the polygons I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR95V.png)

I can plot all the polygons with plot(sector_field), but plot(sector_field[[1,]]) doesn't plot a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question, do not share use files, rather create data through code or use data that ship with R.

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
```

You need to use single brackets to subset

```
p[1,]
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 5.826232, 6.16085, 49.94611, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#variables   : 5
#names       : ID_1,   NAME_1, ID_2,   NAME_2, AREA 
#value       :    1, Diekirch,    1, Clervaux,  312
```

With double brackets you get the values for the first attribute

```
p[[1]]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```